# BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError in Pages#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, amazon-web-services, npm

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have upload code from local to aws with nginx (passanger). Everytime I facing this error(showing in picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44xF7.png)).

```
Error while running `/var/www/4free-backend/node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc -t babelify --fast --list --cachefile=/var/www/4free-backend/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/browserifyinc-cache.json -o "/var/www/4free-backend/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/output20180813-6665-tzjoay" -`:

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/var/www/4free-backend/node_modules/material-ui/package.json'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: Text is searchable, images are not (still). Post the error message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/var/www/4free-backend/node_modules/material-ui/package.json'
    at Error (native)

Comment: That's better. You might as well post the code causing the error.

Comment: Yes, the code is working fine in my local system but I am getting this error on production.

Comment: I understand that, but it would be easier to have the code from the image as text as well.